# Return true if value is in second dimension of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
( 
   [0] => Array ( [category] => Category 1 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [category] => Category 2 ) 
   [2] => Array ( [category] => Category 3 ) 
)
```

I would like to supply a value to a function that then returns true if that value is an existing category.

For example:

```
function valueExists($key, $value) {
    // Function code
    if () {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (valueExists("category", "Category 2")) {
    echo "Category 2 is found in array."
} else {
    echo "Category 2 not found in array."
}
```

How would I loop through each array (based on the second dimension) and create this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = [
   ['category' => 'Category 1'], 
   ['category' => 'Category 2'], 
   ['category' => 'Category 3'], 
];

// true or false
in_array('Category 2', array_column($arr, 'category'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this :

```
// add $arr parameter to pass the array you want to check.
function valueExists($arr, $key, $value) {
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (isset($item[$key]) && $item[$key] == $value) {
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}


$arr = [
   ['category' => 'Category 1'], 
   ['category' => 'Category 2'], 
   ['category' => 'Category 3'], 
];


if (valueExists($arr, "category", "Category 2")) {
    echo "Category 2 is found in array.";
} else {
    echo "Category 2 not found in array.";
}
```

Will outputs :

> Category 2 is found in array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$catArr = [
   ['category'=> "Category 1"], 
   ['category'=> "Category 2"], 
   ['category'=> "Category 3"]
```

];

Solution 1: Returns boolean true/false

```
in_array("Category 23", array_column($catArr, 'category')); //true/false
```

Solution 2: Return index of element

```
if(array_search("Category 1", array_column($catArr, 'category')) > 0){
    //Found
}
```

Solution 3: If has exists multiple times return number of times item exists

```
if(sizeof(array_keys(array_column($catArr, 'category'), "Category 1")) > 0) {
   //Found
}
```